# Jquery Ajax WCF Parameters

Tags: jquery, asp.net, ajax, wcf

I can't get a WCF call to work from jquery while passing two parameters. If I change the code up a bit to pass just one things work ok.

The Javascript:

```
 $.ajax({
    type: "POST", //GET or POST or PUT or DELETE verb
    url: "/Services/JobNumberService.svc/GetActiveJobNumberByCustomerOrJointBilling", // Location of the service
    data: '{"customerId": "' + customerId + '", "departmentId": "' + departmentId + '"}', //Data sent to server
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8", // content type sent to server
    dataType: "json", //Expected data format from server
    processdata: true, //True or False
    success: function (msg) {//On Successfull service call
        fillDropDownFromLookupList(msg, jobNumberDropDownId);

        prependItemToDropDown('', 'NONE', jobNumberDropDownId); //Add blank item to top of list
    },
    error: ServiceFailed// When Service call fails
});
```

Service Signature:

```
public LookupList GetActiveJobNumberByCustomerOrJointBilling(int customerId, int departmentId)
```

It's got to be something with how I'm formatting the json that's passed in. It's valid according to JSONLint but maybe not what .net expects.

Ideas are appreciated.

**EDIT**

This is what I get back in the response

```
HTTP/1.1 500 Internal Server Error
Server: ASP.NET Development Server/11.0.0.0
Date: Thu, 28 Feb 2013 20:30:17 GMT
X-AspNet-Version: 4.0.30319
Cache-Control: private
Content-Length: 0
Connection: Close
```

O, I also tried to turn off just my code debugging to track down what the error was but I wasn't seeing any exceptions for some reason.

Comment: Try stepping through the server-side execution and see what the 500 error is - or turn on verbose error messages in your configuration so that the response will contain the stack trace. That's fairly ambiguous.

Comment: Hey Tony, where's the verbose error setting you're thinking of? I have includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true" in the serviceBehaviors  config section.

Comment: You should be able to get them turned on by editing `web.config` as follows: `<system.web><customErrors mode="On" /></system.web>` - If that doesn't work, let me know and I'll help you dig in further.

Comment: Good idea, I had that flipped to on already sadly

Comment: Gah - that's what I get for typing quickly. `customErrors` needs to be set to `Off` in order to get verbosity.

Comment: I tried both ways for fun while I was in there checking :-)

Comment: Any chance you can step through the server execution and see where it blows up?

Comment: Unfortunately no. If I stick a breakpoint on the first line of my service it doesn't get hit. Even tried turning off just my code for the debugger and still didn't give me anything to work with. Do you have any services where you pass more than one item in? I looked though all my code and it's all just one param.

Comment: Hah... ok - posting an answer - this might help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Based on your comments, I believe your problem may be that you're trying to bind more than one parameter to your endpoint. I'm no WCF expert, but I know that this doesn't work in WebAPI.

The fix, in general, is to create a model for your binding to parse into:

```
public class CustomerModel { 
    public int customerId; 
    public int departmentId; 
}
```

Then make that the expected parameter of your call:

```
public LookupList GetActiveJobNumberByCustomerOrJointBilling(CustomerModel model)
```

Now you just need to drop the quotes from around your JSON object that you're submitting, and your AJAX should work as-is, because the following JSON object will correctly de-serialize into your new `CustomerModel` object:

```
{ "customerId": 1, "departmentId": 1 }
```

If you keep the quotes, you will likely get erroneous results - because the parser will interpret the data it's receiving as a string, rather than a JSON object.

Comment: I'll take it from you marking my answer correct that this helped. :) Glad I could be of assistance!

Answer (score 5):

Your service takes `int` values as parameters, but you are sending it strings. If `customerId` and `departmentId` are numbers, you need to remove the quotes around them so that they'll be interpreted as such.

```
'{"customerId": ' + customerId + ', "departmentId": ' + departmentId + '}'
```

Comment: Didn't think of that, I always use `JSON.stringify` to generate correct JSON.

Comment: I don't think that's the issue. #1, when I just pass one of the parameters the servers gets called ok. #2 I tried it out and didn't work. Let me update the question with what I see error wise

Comment: @AndrewWalters does your service expect json? Do you get the 500 error when you send the values as numbers?

Comment: Ya, same error if you pass the data is as you suggested. I'm sure I'm doing something stupid just need some extra eyes to figure it out